# Algorithm to find inverse of matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse, gaussian-elimination

I've been stuck in this problem for a while now.

[image: Picture of my notes]

This is what the solution is supposed to be.

[image: Solution]

Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not sure what else I can elaborate on this, other than the fact that I hope that my notes were self-explanatory. I'm guessing there is a problem by switching row 2 & 3?

Comment: Are you asking for an explanation of the method used?  Set up an augmented matrix $\left[\begin{array}{c|c}A&I\end{array}\right]$ and row reduce.  The result will be of the form $\left[\begin{array}{c|c}I&A^{-1}\end{array}\right]$.  Are you asking for an explanation of the row reduction algorithm?  See [the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination).  Are you asking for critique on your attempt?  Your handwriting and notation is a bit hard to read, but I'll have a look... give me a moment...

Comment: At a glance, it looks like your very first step, you attempted to add $-1$ times the first row to the third row to replace the third row.  You seem to have missed performing the arithmetic for the third entry.  $-1\cdot 1 + 0 = -1\neq 0$

Comment: Appologies about the handwriting :/ I've tried to use the `[ A | I ]` method, but i kept getting the wrong result. Thats really what this question is about

Comment: @Ole-Johan The last row of your second matrix term is $0 \ 1 \   \color{red}{-1}  \  |  \ -1  \ 0  \ 1$

Comment: Oh wow! It's always the easy mistakes that get me... Thanks guys :) I was blind to that one

Comment: For what its worth, everything else appears correct and you [got the right answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7B%7B1%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C1%7D%7D%5E-1) for finding the inverse of $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\0&1&1\\1&1&\color{blue}{1}\end{bmatrix}$ (*the matrix that would have led you to the second line*).  If graded out of 10 points, worth 9 or more in my opinion.  Showed understanding of the method and theory, just one easily missed typo/simple arithmetical mistake.  Keep up good work with your studies.